# How could to check params from url in web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, parameters, web-config, rules

I want to divide result of this url

```
www.test.com/shop/?wc-ajax=update_order_review
```

With any other url like:

```
www.test.com/shop/?param=update_order_review
www.test.com/shop//
www.test.com/shop
```

And what I looking, result of other Url redirect to another page, like: "http://test.com/products"

Note: This condition only works on /shop/ folder.

```
<rule name="rule01" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)test.com/shop/?wc-ajax=update_order_review" />
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.test.co/products/" ppendQueryString="false" />
<serverVariables>
</serverVariables>
</rule>
```